# Check if login was successful with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm just getting to grips with Selenium, and have made a simple log in script using the Firefox IDE.

What want to do now is check if the log in was successful.

The simplest way I could think of was to search for a piece of text that is only visible after log in i.e. `Hi, [account name]`.

But I'm a little unsure on how to do this with Selenium.

Is there a way you can search for a term on a page and then act, upon its presence?

Also, is this the best way to check if your logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `IDE` it should be a simple case of recording your login action and then where you have your `Hi [username]` element, right-click on it and then in the context menu you should see additional options that are from the `IDE`.

One of those should be `verify text` or `assert text`. Select that, when you then run your `test case` it will complete the login account and verify/assert that the `Hi [username]` text is on the page.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, I am checking for sucessful login by the way that I search for specific label. In my case that label contains ID of logged in user. Example:

```
<span id="username">PAVEL007</span>
```

So, when I log in:

```
driver.get("http://PAVEL007:OmgTooSecretToTellYou!@my-test-site.com");
```

Then I search for that label

```
WebElement loggedInUser = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
```

And verify that I am in:

```
 Assert.assertEquals(loggedInUser.getText(),"PAVEL007");
```

In nutshell:

1. If your website shows some specific text visible only after sucessful login, use that text
2. Best way is not to search for that text itself, but for element containing the text

*NOTE*

The `driver` variable is assumed healthy, living instance of `WebDriver` 
My pseudo code is Java based

Answer (score 3):

Get a url which can be accessed only after login.

```
url = "some url accessed only after login"
driver.navigate_to url
driver.current_url == url ? "logged_in" : "not_logged_in"
```

if not logged in it will be redirected to some other url. This is applicable in websites where url is not created dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you are using selenium IDE, it should very easy case, first of all you have to recording your login action and after login you have Hi [username] text is present on the screen, right-click on that text then select `verifytext` in the the context menu you should see additional options that are from the IDE.

One of those should be `verify text` or `assert text`. Select that, when you then run your test case it will complete the login account and verify/assert that the Hi [username] text is on the page

```
       open | www.gmail.com
       type | id=username |usrename
       type | id=password |password
        Verifytext | HI[Username]|
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is the fluent method:

```
driver.getSource().contains("a string");
```

Personally, I prefer using cssLocator to locate values:

```
if ( driver.findElement(myElement).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("my value") ) //do
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify successful login through assertion. This is my code you can verify

```
    WebElement useremail = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email']"));

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']"));

    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn-signin']"));

    useremail.sendKeys("abc@mailinator.com"); password.sendKeys("XXX");
    login.click(); String actualurl="url";

    String expectedurl= driver.getCurrentUrl();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedurl,actualurl);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about how this answers the question asked? Your answer seems more like a Question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WebDriverWait`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) of `selenium.webdriver.support.ui` to wait for login.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('fieldset'))  # there is also a until_not do the not condition
# do something after the login, if not login after 60 there will throw timeout exception
```